# $a$ is an element of a set of a set of $a$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having a hard time conceptualizing what this means:

$a \in \{\{a\}\}$

Is this saying that the a is an element of the set of set a?

Answer (score 8):

Yep, that's what the statement says. The statement is false, but you have interpreted it correctly.

Comment: A little flaw here: should it be "the *element* $a$ is an element of the set of set of $a$"?

Comment: So, if i'm understanding correctly, it is false because a is defined as an element and an element cannot belong to a set that contains another set of itself?

Comment: Now that I think about it, the correct statement should be the title you gave, however it does not match your post entirely.

Comment: It's true that there is no set fulfilling that relation in standard (ZF) set theory, but that doesn't make the statement false.

Comment: My interpretation is, if $a \in\{\{a\}\}$, then $a = \{a\}$, which seems wrong [from a naive point of view].

Comment: Indeed, $a = \lbrace a \rbrace$ violates the axiom of regularity.

Comment: @xbh Yes, it can. Not in ZF set theory, but logically there is nothing wrong with $a=\{a\}$.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your information. I only have the naive view of this subject.